# how to list bound linux sockets if they are not listening

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, bind

#### Is there a way in linux environment how bound sockets can be inspected if they are not listening?

If a socket is created, bound and listening, than it is listed by `netstat -l`, visible in `/proc/net/<L4 type>`, etc. That's fine.

But IF a socket is only created and bound to a specific TCP/UDP/SCTP port and IP, it is not visible at the mentioned places. The fd is visible under `/proc/<PID>/fd/` with a `socket:[inode]` notation, but it cannot be correlated to any further tables/lists AFAIK. The problem is that, a bound socket prevents other processes in the same network namespace to bind/listen on the same IP/port. It results in `Errno 98: Address already in use`.

So, is it possible to list (or determine the owner process of) the bound, BUT not listening/connected sockets?

Edit:

Let's take [this golang TCP example](https://pastebin.com/ifGvHeL7). You can run it with `go run TCP_bind.go`. If you run it twice, the second run fails.

How would you tell which port is the process bound to? Or the other way around, how would you find who reserved port 55555 when you can not use it with your application?

Comment: have you tried `lsof` ?

Comment: Did my answer suffice your needs?

Comment: @Alnitak : lsof indeed tells that the process has some TCP socket, but it does not tell the IP/port it bound to:
`TCP_bind  3277                libesz    3u     sock                0,8      0t0      70234 protocol: TCP`

Comment: `netstat` and `ss` just read files like `/proc/net/tcp`. Actually, the content of the symlink `/proc/PID/X -> socket:[NUMBER]` contains a "NUMBER" that is an ID from `/proc/net/tcp`. But indeed I see the socket doesn't appear in the table until you call either `listen` or `connect`. Probably because the kernel doesn't know yet if it's a client or a server socket. It looks like you can't do it with `/proc`.

Comment: JOOI, why do you need to detect this?  Isn't the fact that you get `EADDRINUSE` itself a satisfactory diagnostic test?

Comment: And why do you have sockets that are bound but not listening or connected? That is the real problem.

Comment: @EJP That's the whole point, if it happens, how do you know which application is the culprit?

Comment: @o900 The one you just wrote. I've never seen this in 30 years. I'm wondering whether this is the real problem.

Comment: So the original topic was to detect the availability of the port. That is fine with try and fail. Sure.
But then I started to think about the malicious cases, troubleshooting, etc. If somebody gets into any system, he can sit on any amount of popular ports which are allowed by the ulimits and the maybe the non-root port range. If you don't intercept the actual system call with some audit tool like @o9000 wrote below, the detection of the guilty process seems impossible on the available kernel interfaces. It sounds crazy to me :).

Comment: This might be worth asking about on LKML. It looks like a lapse.

Comment: @o9000 I second that - I can't think of any reason there couldn't (shouldn't) be an API to find these bound but not-listening sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux you can use the [audit system](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to log certain events, which include system calls. We can leverage it to find out what process calls [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html).

Assuming Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install auditd
sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S bind -k BIND
```

I've tested with the following Python code, equivalent to your Go code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 55555))
```

The audit log can be searched with `ausearch -i -k BIND`:

```
----
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(04/18/2017 21:29:52.730:19) : auid=ovi ses=1 op="add_rule" key=BIND list=exit res=yes
----
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(04/18/2017 21:29:58.062:20) : auid=ovi ses=1 op="add_rule" key=BIND list=exit res=yes
----
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(04/18/2017 21:31:09.189:33) : proctitle=python
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(04/18/2017 21:31:09.189:33) : saddr=inet host:127.0.0.1 serv:55555
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(04/18/2017 21:31:09.189:33) : arch=x86_64 syscall=bind success=yes exit=0 a0=0x3 a1=0x7fff11c66440 a2=0x10 a3=0x373 items=0 ppid=28677 pid=28693 auid=o9000 uid=o9000 gid=o9000 euid=o9000 suid=o9000 fsuid=o9000 egid=o9000 sgid=o9000
fsgid=o9000 tty=pts1 ses=4 comm=python exe=/usr/bin/python2.7 key=BIND
```

We can see indeed a bind called for host:127.0.0.1 serv:55555 from pid 28693.

Auditing must be enabled before the problematic program is started.

The actual log is stored in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. You might want to set auditd to rotate it, so it doesn't grow indefinitely.

Explanation of the above commands (based on [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-custom-system-audit-rules-on-centos-7)):

- `auditctl -a`: audit system calls ...
- `exit,always`: always audit this system call when it exits (since we want to know if `bind(2)` succeeded)
- `-F arch=b64`: audit 64-bit programs (a separate rule must be created for 32-bit!)
- `-S bind`: audit the `bind` system call
- `-k BIND`: add the label `BIND` to the event in the log
- `ausearch`: Search the audit log ...
- `-i`: convert structures to human readable notation (decodes the IP address and the port number)
- `-k BIND`: show only events labeled as "BIND".